# Windows cant connect to Synology NAS on local network

Tags: networking, nas, smb

This used to work last year.  Mid-last year, after an update it stopped working.  I tracked it down to `Enable NTVLMv1 authentication` which had been unticked by an update.  I ticked it and everything started working.  Yes, I know NTVLMv2 is safer, but changing Windows to use this may break other network things.  One thing at a time.

I tried connecting after two months and I can no longer connect.

- It does not show up in **Network Devices**
- Typing in `\\Gupta-AKL` in **Explorer**, fails after a few minutes `Windows cannot access \\gupta-akl`
- **Diagnosing Problems** says `Computer is configured correctly. Resource gupta-akl is not responding`.
- I can connect to it with the browser at the correct IP address.

The network, router, IP addresses, and passwords have not changed.  The only thing that has changed is that I have a new motherboard and CPU in my PC.

**Settings**

- **SMB** is enabled
- The workgroup is **WORKGROUP** on both
- The NAS shows the address `\\Gupta-AKL` for Windows Explorer connection and that is what I am using.
- Windows Firewall is off
- Malwarebytes has not restricted it in any way.
- I have deleted the saved Windows credentials for it.

**What do I need to do to get it working again?**

### **SMB Settings**

[image: SMB Settings]

### **Advanced General SMB Settings**

[image: General]

### **Advanced Others SMB Settings**

[image: Others]

Comment: what version of windows? NTMLv1 should not be required for anything windows since XPSP1. if for some reason you do need to support SMBv1, note that you have the minimum SMB version set to 2. you will need to set it to v1 if you want clients that only support SMBv1 to connect to it.

Comment: And what happens if you use the IP adress to access SMB? i.e. `\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: It didn't work before with the ipaddress in file explorer.  It does now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the settings above, saved them, changed them back and resaved them.

It started working.  For whatever reason it needed the NTMLv1 setting to be ticked.  I tried with and without.